# Bootstrap Popup window not showing data from server side on Grid View Row Command event, c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have grid view inside an update panel which on click of link button fires grid view row command event. 
On this row command event I want to open a bootstrap popup and bind another grid from code behind which is also in an update panel.

Problem is grid view fires row command event and data is fetched correctly and binds it to the popup grid view but popup does not display's data of newly bound grid view.

I have tried triggers as well for update panel my code is please help me, I am really stuck in this, thanks in advance

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvResponseList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ListId"
                                Width="550px" AllowPaging="True" OnRowCommand="gvResponseList_RowCommand" CssClass="table table_standard_inbox table-striped table-bordered">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Response">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton class="popup" data-toggle="modal" ID="lnkbtnSelectAnswer" Visible='<%#Eval("ResponseTitle") != null %>' runat="server" Text="Choose From Previous Answer" CommandName="AddAnswerToTextBox" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtResponse" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="60px" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                                ValidationGroup="Submit" ControlToValidate="txtResponse" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <br />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <b>No record found</b>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvResponseList" EventName="RowCommand" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="divPreviousResponses" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Prevoius Answers</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvSelectAnswer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ListId"
                                Width="550px" AllowPaging="True" ItemType="TextualUserAnswersEntity" OnRowCommand="gvSelectAnswer_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gvSelectAnswer_PageIndexChanging">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Previous Response">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblResponse2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ResponseTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <b>No record found </b>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resolve this issue in the following way:
1. display the gridView as some HTML table formatted by jQuery's dataTable lib
The data for this table has to be sent as Json by the server side 
2. On click even of your table rows make Ajax call to your server side to get (as Json) some other information you need to display and parse it into the body of your Bootstrap's modal.
All this will perfectly work and what is also important - it will work faster than how you are trying to do it now